# Angular Carousel which prefaces next image - does it exist?

Tags: angular, image, carousel

So, I am trying to implement this design:

[image]

As you see, the picture is in the middle but left and right you can see the end/start of the previous/next image.

I have checked out the angular carousels from https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/angular-carousels/ but none seem to show this unique feature.

I am currently using NgbCarousel so far.

What is the best way to implement this? Is there a library for that already?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you could consider offsetting the first item in the carousel list. How you determine what to offset by how much is up to you as you have not provided any minimal code to work with.

```css
.carousel-item:first-child {
      margin-left: -50px;
    }
```

Other than that, some googling reveals that, indeed there are such packages:

package: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html

example: https://codepen.io/Nurech/pen/wvQxoyb

[image]

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o

Comment: thanks mate, i will check if this will suffice my needs